# inherited hook on Hash

Tags: ruby, hook

```
def Object.inherited(c)
  puts "class #{c} extends #{self}"
end

c = Class.new
#class #<Class:0xcfe57ac> extends Object
#=> #<Class:0xcfe57ac>
```

Works pretty much as expected

```
def Hash.inherited(h)
  puts "The Hash is #{h}"
end

h = Hash.new
#=> {}
```

Why doesn't the hook get called in this case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Class.new` creates a class, which means a class is inherited, and calls `inherited`, but `Hash.new` does not create a class, and does not call `inherited`.

Comment: h.class = Hash and Hash.class = Class, doesn;t this mean it is indirectly inheriting ?

Answer (score 0):

The pickaxe : Class#inherited - cls.inherited( sub_class ) Invoked by Ruby when a subclass of cls is created.

```
def Hash.inherited(sub_class)
  puts "Hash inherited by #{sub_class}"
end

class MySubHash < Hash
end

$ ruby -w t.rb
Hash inherited by MySubHash
```